# SWT create a dismissed widget (scroll through composite)

Tags: java, swt

I wish I could create a composite that I previously disposed. The aim would be to show and hide cyclically composite to change screen (scroll through composite). Thanks in advance.

```
public class prog {
    static public void main(String[] args)  {
        final Display display = new Display();
        final Shell shell     = new Shell  (display, SWT.CLOSE | SWT.TITLE | SWT.MIN );
        shell.setText("EXAMPLE");
        shell.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,false));

        //I want comp1 initially be shown and then being hidden and that is shown comp2 with its components

        final Composite comp1 = new Composite(shell, SWT.NONE);
        comp1.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,false));
        comp1.setLayoutData(new GridData(GridData.FILL, GridData.FILL, true, true));

        final Composite comp2 = new Composite(shell, SWT.BORDER);
        comp2.setLayoutData(new GridData(GridData.FILL, GridData.FILL, true, true));

        GridData data = (GridData)comp2.getLayoutData();  // Assumes layout was set earlier
        data.exclude = true;   // Don't include control in the layout

        comp2.setVisible(false);

        comp2.layout(true);

        Label t = new Label(comp2, SWT.NONE);
        t.setText("must be shown");

        Button btn_create = new Button(comp1, SWT.PUSH);
        btn_create.setText("change composite");
        btn_create.setLayoutData(new GridData(GridData.FILL, GridData.FILL, true, true,1,1));

        btn_create.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {        //evento quando il bottone viene premuto
            public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
                GridData data3 = (GridData)comp1.getLayoutData();  // Assumes layout was set earlier

                data3.exclude =     true;   // Don't include control in the layout

                comp1.setVisible(false);

                comp1.layout(true);

                GridData data2 = (GridData)comp2.getLayoutData();  // Assumes layout was set earlier

                data2.exclude = false;   // Don't include control in the layout

                comp2.setVisible(true);

                comp2.layout(true);
                System.out.println(comp2.getVisible());



            }});

        //swt_create.create(display, shell, create);    
        shell.setSize(500, 100);

        shell.addControlListener(new ControlAdapter() {     // fa in modo che la dimensione della finestra si sempre
            public void controlResized(ControlEvent e) {    // uguale
                shell.setSize(500,400);
            }
        });  
        shell.open();
        shell.pack();        

        while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
              if (!display.readAndDispatch()) {    // questo etodo serve a leggere gli eventi che compiamo durante 
                        display.sleep();           // l'esecuzione, quando si clicca sulla x si passa avanti e il ciclo viene
               }                                   // chiuso 
            }

        display.dispose();
}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once a control has been disposed it is gone and can't be reused.

You can hide a control temporarily by calling `setVisible(false)` on the control to make it invisible.

When you make the control visible / invisible you need to update the layout of the parent Composite. Depending on the Layout you are using for the Composite you may need to adjust the layout as well.

For example if you are using `GridLayout` for the parent composite you can use the `exclude` option of `GridData` to leave out the control:

```
GridData data = (GridData)control.getLayoutData();  // Assumes layout was set earlier

data.exclude = true;   // Don't include control in the layout

control.setVisible(false);

....

parentComposite.layout(true);
```

To show the control reverse the settings:

```
GridData data = (GridData)control.getLayoutData();  // Assumes layout was set earlier

data.exclude = false;   // Include control in the layout

control.setVisible(true);

....

parentComposite.layout(true);
```

Comment: you could do so. but then I is shown in the space with nothing in it, I wish it was shown only what I want.

Comment: Depending on the layout you use you can arrange not to have any empty space. I added an example for GridLayout.

Comment: I managed to make it invisible ... now how do I make visible the second composite and hide first?

Comment: You use 'exclude = false' and 'setVisible(true)' for the part you want to show and the reverse for the part you want to hide.